# Qual a melhor maneira de usar as Media Queries

Tags: html5, media-queries

Qual a melhor maneira de usar o Media Queries para responsivo o `max-width:` ou  `min-width:`

Answer (score 4):

Na verdade, os dois jeitos estão corretos. não há diferenças de performance ou outra coisa, são apenas filtros diferentes.

Existe os dois, pois caso você queira aplicar o css dentro de um intervalo, você pode usá-los dessa forma: min-width: 500px and max-width: 800px